# Project output will not be moved to output folder(py installer)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my script(thousand lines) to exe. I have nearly 50 modules for importing in my code. For converting, I used `pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py`, but it gave an error. Also I used auto-py-to-exe program, but same error. Then I made a simple gui for trying whether my converting method is right or wrong. Fortunately, it worked. After that i just copy my 50modules to that simple-running script, then try to convert. And i got same error. However i can able to run myscipt in python(so modules are running). I dont understand what the problem is.

I wrote my script with Python 3.7 and used pyinstaller both in Python 3.7 and 2.7. Below example run with two module and convertable to exe, but with those 50 modules, no way.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import sys, os 
import wx
import wx.grid
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import datetime 
import mplcursors 
import time
import math
import numpy as np
import _thread  
import copy
import colorsys
import functools
import matplotlib                                                                   ### .ticker
import matplotlib as mpl                                                            
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                     
from math import pi
from matplotlib.figure import Figure                                                
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar    
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pygeodesy.sphericalNvector import LatLon  
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
from datetime import datetime as dt                    
from wx.lib import analogclock as ac                                                   
from wx.lib.delayedresult import startWorker
from wx.lib import masked
from wx.lib.masked import TextCtrl
from haversine import haversine
from skimage import io              #from PIL import *
try:
    from agw import speedmeter as SM
except ImportError: # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM
try:
    from agw import pygauge as PG
except ImportError: # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    try:
        import wx.lib.agw.pygauge as PG
    except:
        raise Exception("This demo requires wxPython version greater than 2.9.0.0")

#below modules are enough for run this
import wx
import os


wildcard = "Python source (*.txt)|*.txt|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"
class MyFrame11 ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.m_button121 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_button121, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textCtrl12 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrl12, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.btn = True

        self.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        # Connect Events
        self.m_button121.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn_f )


    def btn_f( self, event ):
        if self.btn:
            self.m_textCtrl12.SetValue("hey")
            self.btn = False
        else:
            self.m_textCtrl12.Clear()
            self.btn = True



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame11(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And traces like this:

```
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 230, in convert
    pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 541, in assemble
    priority_scripts = self.graph.analyze_runtime_hooks(self.custom_runtime_hooks) + priority_scripts
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 514, in analyze_runtime_hooks
    rthooks_nodes.append(self.run_script(path))
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 219, in run_script
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname, caller=caller)
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1331, in run_script
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\loader\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_nltk.py'

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Check that line `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\loader\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_nltk.py'`

Comment: @Abitbol, thanks for concerning. No such file **pyi_rth_nltk.py** but **pyi_rth__nltk.py** with included extra **"_"**. In it, `import sys
import os
import nltk

#add the path to nltk_data
nltk.data.path.append(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "nltk_data"))`

Comment: Could it be an incomplete installation of pyinstaller? Consider doing a "pip uninstall pyinstaller" and installing it again

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running pyinstaller in cmd as admin, therefore changing you directory to `C:\Windows\System32` before running `pyinstaller` try using `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. This will ensure that you are using a directory that you have permission to use. `%USERPROFILE%` means your user folder, from there we go to your desktop. It might also be that you have a currupt installation of pyinstaller. Try using `pip uninstall pyinstaller` and then `pip install pyinstaller`. This just reinstalls pyinstaller. The last solution might be that you do not have those modules with your .exe use `--hidden import` to add an import or module to your exe. You can do this as many times as you need to when you are running your command.